# date format with extjs 4 not rendering in date picker

Tags: extjs4.1

I have the following date picker

```
{
                                xtype: 'datefield',
                                id: 'FinalDespatchDate',
                                name: 'FinalDespatchDate',
                                fieldLabel: 'Part Despatch Date',
                                labelWidth: 150,
                                width: 370,
                                validateOnChange: false,
                                format: 'd/m/Y' 
                            },

In my model i have 

  {
             mapping:'FinalDespatchDate',
             name:'FinalDespatchDate',
             type: 'date',
             dateFormat:'d/m/Y'
         },
```

if in my model i don't include the dateFormat. The date binds to my date picker but it sends the date in an incorrect format. When i add dateFormat it sends the date in the correct format it just no longer binds to the datepicker. ie the above configuration display nothing in the date picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your data come from server with properly formatted date value ('d/m/Y') in this (non-working) configuration?